# React dnd - Drop and Drag to Change value of an input

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm new to react and I'm using a library called react-dnd. I'm trying to make a draggable component(a dice which is just a number) to move its value as a value of a droppable input component's(number input in a form) value(ss is attached).

currently; it us just console logging the draggable component when I drop it to the droppable component. But what I want is to change the value of the input when I drop into the droppable component. I tried many ways but I couldn't get the droppable component to show the value taken from the draggable compont. How can I move the value from left to right and keep it as a value in the input form.

**draggable component**

```
  export default function Dice({ id = null, dice = 0 }) {
  const [, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { type: ItemTypes.DICE, id: id },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });

  return (
    <div ref={drag} className='dice' id={id}>
      <span>{dice}</span>
    </div>
  );
```

**droppable component**

```
  const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: ItemTypes.DICE,
    drop: (item, monitor) => {
      console.log(item);
    },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
    }),
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={drop}
        id={props.id}
        name={props.name}
        value={props.value}
        type={props.type}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        required
        min={props.min ? props.min : 1}
        max={props.max ? props.max : 150}
        minLength={props.minLength ? props.minLength : 0}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwxOa.jpg)

Comment: What is the actual question? You only described what you did so far.

Comment: drop: (item, monitor) => {
      console.log(item);
    },
right now; it is just console logging the draggable component when I drop it to the droppable component. But what I want is to change the value of the input when I drop into the droppable component. I tried many ways but I couldn't get the droppable component to show the value taken from the draggable component.